# Unable to resolve module React-Native

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm following a tutorial however have not been able to get any help from the course owner or fellow students so please help. 
I'm encountering the Unable to resolve module error seen below in Windows 10. 
This has been after I have created a new react native project, executing all the commands from the command line:

```
react-native init techstack
```

And then adding within command line of the project directory:

```
npm install --save redux react-redux
```

I have followed the advice given in the error message running first:

```
npm rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

And then

```
npm watchman watch-del-all
```

And finally trying:

```
npm rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
```

And also:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

However no matter what I tried it still did not resolve the issue and the exact same error persisted

[image]

Comment: you get this error when you run `react-native run-android` in the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the error came from not finding the `src/app` module. It's not from the `node-modules` or `watchman`. Check the imports in the `index.android.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Please enter ./src/app  instead of .src/app